# git: --graph/--oneline graph marker characters for root commits

Tags: git

git has rich log formatting features that allow to format repository commit logs in various ways. I usually prefer `--graph` and `--oneline` options to make the history look more "natural" and make it more compact respectively. In one of my repositories I use branches without common parents, so `git log --graph --oneline master orphan` produces something like this:

```
* 667788 (orphan) Orphan message 1
* 334455 (master) Master message 2
* 001122 (master) Master message 1
```

Commits `001122` and `667788` are root commits, but they are not visually recognizable as roots. Is it possible to make graph/oneline render another character, not `*`, for root commits so they could be easily recognizable?
 For example, something like

```
@ 667788 (orphan) Orphan message 1
* 334455 (master) Master message 2
@ 001122 (master) Master message 1
```

would be great. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Only by modifying the `git log --graph` source code. If you omit the `--oneline` specification (or otherwise insert lines between commits) the `--graph` output becomes unambiguous, but right now there's no other way to get Git to show this so well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alias that can work more or less:

```
x-log = "!f() { \
    git log --graph --no-abbrev-commit $@ \
    | sed 's/* \\(\\x1b\\[[0-9;]*m\\)\\?\\(commit \\)\\?\\('"$(echo -n $(git rev-list --max-parents=0 --no-abbrev-commit --all) | sed 's/ /\\\\|/g')"'\\)/@ \\1\\2\\3/g'; \
}; f"
```

"Experimental" `log` is implemented as follows:

- It can accept arbitrary number of arguments using the bash function `f` declaration/invocation pattern.
- All `x-log` arguments are passed to the backing `log` command which sets the graph mode and forces the full commits SHA-1 output, no abbreviations.
- The `sed` pattern is generally `'s/* \(\x1b\[[0-9;]*m\)\?\(commit \)\{0,1\}\('"$(echo -n $(git rev-list --max-parents=0 --no-abbrev-commit --all) | sed 's/ /\\|/g')"'\)/@ \1\2\3/g'` but requires double slash escapes to work as a Git alias:

  - `*` - The default graph node markers.
  - `\(\x1b\[[0-9;]*m\)\?` - Optional ANSI escapes pattern (color support; the regex pattern is borrowed from https://superuser.com/questions/380772/removing-ansi-color-codes-from-text-stream).
  - `\(commit \)\?` - Optional `commit` that appear in both regular and graph `log` results.
  - `\('"$(echo -n $(git rev-list --max-parents=0 --no-abbrev-commit --all) | sed 's/ /\\|/g')"'\)` - This one seems to be a good candidate for "it can be done in another way" (I don't know if it's done right). `git rev-list --max-parents=0 --all` retrieves SHA-1 hashes for all root commits. These hashes should be joined via a `sed`-escaped pipe (`\|`) in a single line without a trailing new line (`echo -n` does it well).
  - `@ \1\2\3` - Renders the output with the root marker `@` and the above capture groups: `\1` is the optional ANSI pattern, `\2` is the optional word "commit", `\3` is a commit SHA-1 hash respectively.

This alias has the following limitations:

- It does not work with abbreviated commits (therefore `git x-log --oneline` will not work because it implies `--abbrev-commit` unless it's overridden with `--no-abbrev` explicitly), but it can be improved or switched to `--abbrev-commit` by modifying the alias source code globally.
- It disables the default pager settings because git output is written to a pipe in order to be processed with `sed`, and not directly to stdout.
- It also disables the default color support.
- It relies on regexps heavily.

Some examples:

#### `git x-log --all --color=always`

```
@ commit 411104dcfa8ed1e5c2b09f8ce26971a46ab4e64a
  Author: - <->
  Date:   Sun Dec 17 16:50:26 2017 +0200

      Orphan message 1

* commit a6485cee4bd1d4d8f23e2bd27b3678f40f5b7a26
| Author: - <->
| Date:   Sun Dec 17 16:48:57 2017 +0200
| 
|     Master message 2
| 
@ commit ce45a56a31369e83544adb8c18ee346185ad6380
  Author: - <->
  Date:   Sun Dec 17 16:48:45 2017 +0200

      Master message 1
```

#### `git x-log --all --oneline --color=always`

(No `@` characters because this alias only works when `no-abbrev-commit` is active, and `--abbrev-commit` is set by `--oneline` automatically)

```
* 411104d Orphan message 1
* a6485ce Master message 2
* ce45a56 Master message 1
```

#### `git x-log --all --pretty=oneline --color=always`

```
@ 411104d Orphan message 1
* a6485ce Master message 2
@ ce45a56 Master message 1
```

I tested it today on my Windows Git installation, but I believe it should work on Linux as well.
And yes, it would be really cool if Git could support this out of box.

Comment: This is fantastic!  I'm using it with `--format=tformat:...` (custom `--pretty=oneline`) to append a newline to the root commit, and still change its decoration to a `@`.  Not escaped for being a git alias, changed `/@ \1\2\3/g'` to `\(.*\)/@ \1\2\3\4\n/g'`.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make some tiny changes to git.
A new boolean `log.showRootMark` configuration option enables `@` indicator for initial commits.
The default behavior remains unchanged.

#### `git -c log.showRootMark log --graph --oneline`

```
@ 667788 (orphan) Orphan message 1
* 334455 (master) Master message 2
@ 001122 (master) Master message 1
```

#### `git log --graph --oneline`

```
* 667788 (orphan) Orphan message 1
* 334455 (master) Master message 2
* 001122 (master) Master message 1
```

The patch (initially put on top of [`c2a499e6c31ed613a606ffdeb5bb74ab41e9a586`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2a499e6c31ed613a606ffdeb5bb74ab41e9a586)):

```
 Documentation/config.txt  |  5 +++++
 Documentation/git-log.txt |  5 +++++
 graph.c                   | 20 ++++++++++++++++++++
 t/t4202-log.sh            | 16 ++++++++++++++++
 4 files changed, 46 insertions(+)

diff --git a/Documentation/config.txt b/Documentation/config.txt
index 4e0cff87f..0a32357e3 100644
--- a/Documentation/config.txt
+++ b/Documentation/config.txt
@@ -2254,6 +2254,11 @@ log.showRoot::
    Tools like linkgit:git-log[1] or linkgit:git-whatchanged[1], which
    normally hide the root commit will now show it. True by default.

+log.showRootMark::
+   If true, the initial commit in `git log --graph` will be marked
+   with the at sign (`@`). Otherwise the initial commit will be
+   marked with the default asterisk sign (`*`). False by default.
+
 log.showSignature::
    If true, makes linkgit:git-log[1], linkgit:git-show[1], and
    linkgit:git-whatchanged[1] assume `--show-signature`.
diff --git a/Documentation/git-log.txt b/Documentation/git-log.txt
index 5437f8b0f..7f5436231 100644
--- a/Documentation/git-log.txt
+++ b/Documentation/git-log.txt
@@ -205,6 +205,11 @@ log.showRoot::
    `git log -p` output would be shown without a diff attached.
    The default is `true`.

+log.showRootMark::
+   If true, the initial commit in `git log --graph` will be marked
+   with the at sign (`@`). Otherwise the initial commit will be
+   marked with the default asterisk sign (`*`). False by default.
+
 log.showSignature::
    If `true`, `git log` and related commands will act as if the
    `--show-signature` option was passed to them.
diff --git a/graph.c b/graph.c
index e1f6d3bdd..d14ffec7a 100644
--- a/graph.c
+++ b/graph.c
@@ -80,6 +80,7 @@ static void graph_show_line_prefix(const struct diff_options *diffopt)

 static const char **column_colors;
 static unsigned short column_colors_max;
+static int show_root_mark;

 static void parse_graph_colors_config(struct argv_array *colors, const char *string)
 {
@@ -256,6 +257,16 @@ void graph_setup_line_prefix(struct diff_options *diffopt)
 }


+static int git_graph_config(const char *var, const char *value, void *cb)
+{
+   if (!strcmp(var, "log.showrootmark")) {
+       show_root_mark = git_config_bool(var, value);
+       return 0;
+   }
+
+   return git_default_config(var, value, cb);
+}
+
 struct git_graph *graph_init(struct rev_info *opt)
 {
    struct git_graph *graph = xmalloc(sizeof(struct git_graph));
@@ -276,6 +287,7 @@ struct git_graph *graph_init(struct rev_info *opt)
                        custom_colors.argc - 1);
        }
    }
+   git_config(git_graph_config, NULL);

    graph->commit = NULL;
    graph->revs = opt;
@@ -835,6 +847,14 @@ static void graph_output_commit_char(struct git_graph *graph, struct strbuf *sb)
        return;
    }

+   /*
+    * If the commit has no parents, it's a root commit
+    */
+   if (show_root_mark && !graph->num_parents) {
+       strbuf_addch(sb, '@');
+       return;
+   }
+
    /*
     * get_revision_mark() handles all other cases without assert()
     */
diff --git a/t/t4202-log.sh b/t/t4202-log.sh
index 25b1f8cc7..350e35264 100755
--- a/t/t4202-log.sh
+++ b/t/t4202-log.sh
@@ -455,6 +455,22 @@ test_expect_success 'simple log --graph' '
    test_cmp expect actual
 '

+cat > expect <<EOF
+* Second
+* sixth
+* fifth
+* fourth
+* third
+* second
+@ initial
+EOF
+
+test_expect_success 'simple log --graph' '
+   test_config log.showRootMark true &&
+   git log --graph --pretty=tformat:%s >actual &&
+   test_cmp expect actual
+'
+
 cat > expect <<EOF
 123 * Second
 123 * sixth
-- 
2.16.2
```

## Update #1

This is an insufficient patch. Because:

- Basically, `get_revision_mark` should be responsible for returning a mark, but it seems to be unable to be aware of commit graph parent node count (the `git_graph` structure is only declared in `graph.c` + this must be properly changed). Therefore I can't seem to make it work for `rev-list`.
- Additionally, the patch does not introduce a command-line option. I didn't have enough time to take a look how it's done in the Git codebase.
- This patch does not work for `--left-right` (can be easily implemented though).

  - Are `[` and `]` good enough for this case?
- etc: https://marc.info/?l=git&m=152261624606630